# SQL LIMIT by number of groups?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to implement a search function with pagination on a hierarchical set of data.

It it important to NOT use inner select

This is my tasks table, I'm using supermother_id to define hierarchy groups

```
| id | name     | mother_id | supermother_id | depth |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Task 1   | null      | 1              | 1     |
| 2  | Task 1.1 | 1         | 1              | 2     |
| 3  | Task 2   | null      | 3              | 1     |
| 4  | Task 2.1 | 3         | 3              | 2     |
```

Now, let's say I want to query tasks that contains "1" in their name, limiting to 2 results.

```
SELECT name 
FROM tasks
WHERE name LIKE '%1%' 
ORDER BY supermother_id
LIMIT 2
```

This would return me `Task 1` and `Task 1.1`

What I actually want is for it to return `Task 1`, `Task 1.1` and `Task 2.1`, because the first two are in the same group, I want `LIMIT` to consider them as one.

So since I want `LIMIT 2` to return **3** records, `LIMIT` is probably not the right tool...

So, I want `LIMIT` to only consider distinct values of `supermother_id`, is this possible in a single query?

Comment: I don't think your query is correct in Postgres.  I would expect it to return an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff possibly, I haven't tested it, just wrote the test directly in stackoverflow, if you know the error please let me know

Comment: . . `select *` with `group by` is almost always going to fail.

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, double quotes are for delimited identifiers. (I assume you have no column named `%1%`...)

Comment: Thanks, all fixed I believe

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dense_rank window function partitioned on supermother_id:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
  select *, dense_rank() OVER  (ORDER BY supermother_id) from tasks
) sub
WHERE name like '%1%'
AND dense_rank <= 2;
```

Comment: Isn't this technically two queries? I'm worried about doing 2 selects because hierarchical data can get exponentially complex

Comment: It's one query that includes a subquery.  The performance bottleneck on that query is almost certainly going to be the `LIKE %1%` part, but you won't know until you test it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `distinct on` to get one row per `supermother_id`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (supermother_id) t.* 
FROM tasks t
WHERE t.name LIKE '%1%' 
ORDER BY supermother_id
LIMIT 0,2;
```

Comment: Hmm not really, I tried to word the question better